# How to do spatial left joins with a multiple join query

Tags: sql, spatial-query, oracle-spatial

I have some data I'm trying to query thats a mix of spatial data and some non spatial data. Some of these tables contain a MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY spatial data, some don't.

My query is so far as shown:

```
select table1.col1, table1.col2, table2.col5, table2.col3, table3.col1, table3.col2, table4.col9, **table5.col1** -- this is the data from spatial join
from table1
left join table2 on
table2.col1 = table1.col1
left join table3 on
table3.col5 = table1.col6
left join table4 on
table4.col2 = table1.col1
left join table5 on
--**spatial geometry where spatial geometry in column 3 of table1 is within spatial geometry of table5 column 2**
group by table1.col1, table1.col2, table2.col5, table2.col3, table3.col1, table3.col2, table4.col9
```

My question is, how do I do this? Everything I've found out on spatial left joins don't involve joining other non spatial tables.
This is for SQL Developer Oracle

Answer (score 0):

To join 2 tables with their geometry (SDO_GEOMETRY) columns, you can use the [SDO_JOIN operator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/spatial-operators-reference.html#GUID-4D9DD9EF-DD9C-4198-A416-37B900B4E32F).